# Problem in using System.currentTimeMillis(); in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I tried to observe the time taken by different inputs in the calculation of the nth Fibonacci number, but the output is <50ms for the first input and 0 ms for the rest
Why so?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class fib{
    long fibo(int s){
        if(s==1 ||s==2)
        return 1;
        else return fibo(s-1)+(s-2);
    }
}
class fibrec{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException{
        BufferedWriter wr=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/91887/desktop/books/java/foo3.txt"));
        fib f=new fib();
        Random rand=new Random();
        int input[]=new int[10];
        for(int p=0;p<10;p++){
            long st=System.currentTimeMillis();
            int i=rand.nextInt(12000);
            wr.write("Input : "+i+"\nOutput : "+f.fibo(i)+"\n");
            long et=System.currentTimeMillis();
            wr.write("Time taken = "+(et-st)+"ms\n\n");
            System.out.println(st+"\t"+et+"\t"+(et-st));
        }

        wr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Input : 2348
Output : 2753032
Time taken = 35ms

Input : 7718
Output : 29772187
Time taken = 1ms

Input : 8485
Output : 35984887
Time taken = 0ms

Input : 6620
Output : 21902272
Time taken = 0ms

Input : 2671
Output : 3563116
Time taken = 0ms

Input : 6244
Output : 19484404
Time taken = 0ms

Input : 5370
Output : 14410397
Time taken = 0ms

Input : 2340
Output : 2734292
Time taken = 0ms

Input : 6547
Output : 21421786
Time taken = 0ms

Input : 7580
Output : 28716832
Time taken = 0ms

Comment: Related: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java). Among other things, it says "Make sure you run it for long enough to be able to measure the results in seconds or (better) tens of seconds" and "Use a library for your benchmark".

Answer (score 2):

The granularity of the millisecond clock is *at best* one millisecond<sup>1</sup>.

But apparently, the execution times for your loop iterations are less than one millisecond.  Sub-millisecond time intervals cannot be measured accurately using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.  That is why you are getting zeros.

The explanation for the first measurement being 35 milliseconds is that this is due to JVM warmup effects.  These may include:

- time taken to load and initialize library code<sup>2</sup>,
- time taken to JIT compile code, and
- time taken up with a (possible) GC during or after loading and JIT compilation.

Secondly, I notice that your time measurement includes the time taken to print the number.  You should move that *after* the second call to get the clock value because it could be significant.

Finally, it you want to get reproducible results, you should explicitly seed `Random` yourself rather than relying on the OS to give you a random seed.   And I'm not convinced that you should be benchmarking a Fibonacci algorithm with random inputs anyway ...

---

<sup>1 - The numbers in your output suggest that it is actually 1 millisecond ...</sup>

<sup>2 - For example, the initialization and construction of a `Random` instance entails an OS call to get some "entropy" to seed the random number generator.  That *should be* fast, but there are circumstances where it may not be.  In your case, this happens before you start measuring time ...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The code between the two calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()` is executing too fast (after the first iteration) for any difference to be captured. You'd be able to see a difference if you were using `System.nanoTime()`.

As for why the first iteration is slower than the subsequent ones, that would be because Java uses a Just In Time (JIT) compiler to optimise code at runtime.